# Coin Flip and Counter Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

So I'm trying to make this coin flip but it keeps flipping forever... when I want it to stop after 10 times. I also need a counter variable that tells me how many times it is flipped.

```
var coin = randomNumber (0,1);

write (coin);
while (coin < 10) {
  coin = randomNumber (0,1);
  write (coin);
}
```

Comment: Where' is the `randomNumber` function? I would guess that function always returns a number less than 10. What is `write`? And, if you are trying to do a coin flip, why are you testing to see if the number is less than 10? You just want to see if the number is even or odd and equate even with heads and odd with tails?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just use a `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var coin = randomNumber (0, 1);
  write (coin);
}
```

See this for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

If you want to stick to the `while` loop:

```
var timesFlipped = 0;
while (timesFlipped < 10) {
  var coin = randomNumber (0, 1);
  write (coin);
  timesFlipped = timesFlipped + 1;  // alternatively: timesFlipped++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us your `randomNumber` function, but it's likely that it only produces numbers that are less than `10`. Since your `while` loop says to keep going as long as `coin` is less than `10`, the loop goes forever.

`while` loops are notorious for resulting in infinite loops. I personally never use them. Since you know how many times you need to loop, a counting loop is the correct choice.

Here's what you need:

```js
// Write the function that gets random number and report the results a certain number of times:
function coinToss(numTimes) {
  // Instead of a while loop, use a counting loop that will 
  // have a definite end point
  for(var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++){

    // Get a random number from 0 to 1
    var coin = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    // Test to see if it is even or odd by checking to see if
    // it is divisible by 2 with no remainder.
    var even = (coin % 2 === 0);

    // Report the results
    console.log("The coin was " + (even ? "heads " : " tails"));
  }
}

// Now, call the function and tell it how many times to loop
coinToss(10);
```